# Gekko optimization

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, gekko

I'm solving this optimization problem where I need to figure out **how many distribution centers** I need to open in order to fulfill the demand of the 12 company facilities, while **minimizing the transportation costs**. The transportation costs are simply the distance between the distribution centers times the cost per mile, however in this problem, the cost per mile is one dollar. I have 5 choices which are Boston, Nashua, Providence, Springfield and Worcester, these 5 are part of the 12 company facilities.

I solved the problem and got the correct answer but then I tried to add two constraints to the same code and the answer I get is incorrect. The two other constraints are that the average distance from the distribution centers (DC) to the other facilities (customer) has to be less than 60 miles; and the second constraint is that the percentage of customers within 50 miles has to be greater than 80% (0.8). I know **the answer to this problem**, the cost has to be **$66,781 dollars**, the average customer distance is **15 miles** and the percentage of customers within 50 miles is **90%**. **The output of my code** is that the cost is **$66289** dollars, the average customer distance is **15.36** miles and the percentage of customers within 50 miles is **179%**, which doesn't make sense.

Can you help me figure out why am I getting an odd output? Thanks in advance.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math

m = GEKKO(remote=False) #So that it solves the problem locally
m.options.SOLVER = 1 #MILP

varx = [[0 for col in range(12)] for row in range(5)] #Creates an empty list
for i in range (5):
    for j in range (12):
        varx[i][j] = m.Var(lb = 0, integer = True) 

varx = np.array(varx)    
varxt = np.transpose(varx)



vary = np.empty([]) #Creates an empty array

for i in range(5):
    vary = np.append(vary, m.Var(lb = 0, ub = 1, integer = True)) #Yes/No variables

vary = vary[1:13] 



dists = np.array([[0 , 93, 69, 98, 55, 37, 128, 95, 62, 42, 82, 34], #Boston
                 [37, 65, 33, 103, 20, 0, 137, 113, 48, 72, 79, 41], #Nashua
                 [42, 106, 105, 73, 92, 72, 94, 57, 104, 0, 68, 38], #Providence
                 [82, 59, 101, 27, 93, 79, 63, 57, 127, 68, 0,  47], #Springfield
                 [34, 68, 72, 66, 60, 41, 98, 71, 85, 38, 47,   0]]) #Worcester



max_dist = 60 #Max average distance (in miles)
min_pct = 0.8 #Min percent of demand within 50 miles



aij = np.zeros((5, 12)) #Creates an empty array

for i in range (5):
    for j in range (12):
        if dists[i][j] <= 50:
            aij[i][j] = 1
        else:
            aij[i][j] = 0 #Creates a 0s and 1s array. If the distance to a costumer 
                          #is less than 50, then the matrix element is 1, it is zero
                          #otherwise


dem_consts = np.array([425, 12, 43, 125, 110, 86, 129, 28, 66, 320, 220, 182])

fixd_cost = 10000


sum1 = np.sum(np.multiply(varx, dists))
sum2 = np.sum(vary*fixd_cost)
z = sum1 + sum2 

tot_dem = np.sum(dem_consts)

M = tot_dem



m.Minimize(z)



for i in range(12):
    m.Equation(np.sum(varxt[i, :]) >= dem_consts[i]) #Demand constraints

for i in range(5):
    m.Equation(np.sum(varx[i, :]) <= 2000) #Capacity constraints
    m.Equation(np.sum(varx[i, :]) <= M*vary[i]) #Enforces 0 or 1 value

m.Equation(np.sum(vary[:]) >= 1)


di_sum = np.sum(np.multiply(varx, dists))
di_sumw = di_sum/ tot_dem
m.Equation(di_sumw <= max_dist) #Average (demand) weighted distance from DC to customer

a_sum = np.sum(np.multiply(varx, aij)) 
a_sumw = a_sum/tot_dem
m.Equation(a_sumw >= min_pct) #Percent of demand that is within 50 miles

m.solve(disp = False)


p1 = np.zeros((5, 12))

for i in range (5):
    for j in range (12):
        p1[i][j] = varx[i][j].value[0]
p1t = np.transpose(p1)

p2 = np.zeros((5, )) 

for i in range(5):
    p2[i] = vary[i].value[0] 

mad1 = np.sum(np.multiply(p1, dists)) 
mad2 = mad1/tot_dem
mpi1 = np.sum(np.multiply(p1, aij)) 
mpi2 = mpi1/tot_dem

tot1 = np.sum(np.multiply(p1, dists))
tot2 = np.sum(p2)*fixd_cost
tot = tot1 + tot2 


print('The minimum cost is:' +str(tot))
print('Average customer distance:' +str(mad2))
print('Percent of customers <= 50 miles:' +str(mpi2))


dc = np.array(['Boston', 'Nashua', 'Providence', 'Springfield', 'Worcester'])
cities = ['Boston', 'Brattleboro', 'Concord', 'Hartford', 'Manchester', 'Nashua',
          'New Haven', 'New London', 'Portsmouth', 'Providence', 'Springfield', 'Worcester']
data = {cities[0]: p1t[0], cities[1]: p1t[1], cities[2]: p1t[2], cities[3]: p1t[3],
       cities[4]: p1t[4], cities[5]: p1t[5], cities[6]: p1t[6], cities[7]: p1t[7],
       cities[8]: p1t[8], cities[9]: p1t[9], cities[10]: p1t[10], cities[11]: p1t[11]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = dc)
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a message from the solver that it terminated early at 500 iterations when you set `m.solve(disp=True)`. It returns a feasible integer solution but it may not be the best one.

```
 Warning: best integer solution returned after maximum MINLP iterations
 Adjust minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol  500  in apopt.opt to change limit
 Successful solution

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  1.3654 sec
 Objective      :  66829.
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------


The minimum cost is:66829.0
Average customer distance:15.3659793814433
Percent of customers <= 50 miles:1.7943871706758305
```

If you add the solver options:

```py
m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-2',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 5000']
```

The objective function improves to 66285:

```
 Successful solution

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  1.7178 sec
 Objective      :  66285.
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------


The minimum cost is:66285.0
Average customer distance:20.781786941580755
Percent of customers <= 50 miles:1.9873997709049256
```

Should the percent of customers <= 50 miles be this instead?: `mpi3 = mpi1/np.sum(p1)` and the average distance be?: `mad3 = mad1/np.sum(p1)`. This gives the fraction of customers <= 50 miles equal to 89.94%:

```
Percent of customers <= 50 miles (mpi3):0.8994297563504406
```

The new average distance is:

```
Average customer distance (mad3):9.405132192846034
```

Here is a modified script that uses gekko arrays and gekko sum functions so that it is more efficient.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math

m = GEKKO(remote=False) #So that it solves the problem locally
m.options.SOLVER = 1 #MILP

varx = m.Array(m.Var,(5,12),lb=0,integer=True)
vary = m.Array(m.Var,5,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)

dists = np.array([[0 , 93, 69, 98, 55, 37, 128, 95, 62, 42, 82, 34], #Boston
                 [37, 65, 33, 103, 20, 0, 137, 113, 48, 72, 79, 41], #Nashua
                 [42, 106, 105, 73, 92, 72, 94, 57, 104, 0, 68, 38], #Providence
                 [82, 59, 101, 27, 93, 79, 63, 57, 127, 68, 0,  47], #Springfield
                 [34, 68, 72, 66, 60, 41, 98, 71, 85, 38, 47,   0]]) #Worcester

max_dist = 60 #Max average distance (in miles)
min_pct = 0.8 #Min percent of demand within 50 miles

#Creates a 0s and 1s array. If the distance to a costumer 
#is less than 50, then the matrix element is 1, it is zero otherwise
aij = [[1 if dists[i,j]<=50 else 0 for j in range(12)] for i in range(5)]

dem_consts = np.array([425, 12, 43, 125, 110, 86, 129, 28, 66, 320, 220, 182])
fixd_cost = 10000
sum1 = np.sum(np.multiply(varx, dists))
sum2 = np.sum(vary*fixd_cost)
z = sum1 + sum2 
tot_dem = np.sum(dem_consts)
M = tot_dem
m.Minimize(z)

for j in range(12):
    m.Equation(m.sum(varx[:,j]) >= dem_consts[j]) #Demand constraints

for i in range(5):
    m.Equation(m.sum(varx[i,:]) <= 2000) #Capacity constraints
    m.Equation(m.sum(varx[i,:]) <= M*vary[i]) #Enforces 0 or 1 value

m.Equation(m.sum(vary) >= 1)


di_sum = np.sum(np.multiply(varx, dists))
di_sumw = di_sum/ tot_dem
m.Equation(di_sumw <= max_dist) #Average (demand) weighted distance from DC to customer

a_sum = np.sum(np.multiply(varx, aij)) 
a_sumw = m.Intermediate(a_sum/tot_dem)
m.Equation(a_sumw >= min_pct) #Percent of demand that is within 50 miles


m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-2',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 5000']
m.solve(disp = True)


p1 = np.zeros((5, 12))

for i in range (5):
    for j in range (12):
        p1[i][j] = varx[i][j].value[0]
p1t = np.transpose(p1)

p2 = np.zeros(5) 
for i in range(5):
    p2[i] = vary[i].value[0] 

mad1 = np.sum(np.multiply(p1, dists)) 
mad2 = mad1/tot_dem
mad3 = mad1/np.sum(p1)
mpi1 = np.sum(np.multiply(p1, aij)) 
mpi2 = mpi1/tot_dem
mpi3 = mpi1/np.sum(p1)

tot1 = np.sum(np.multiply(p1, dists))
tot2 = np.sum(p2)*fixd_cost
tot = tot1 + tot2 

print(p1)
print(p2)
print('The minimum cost is:' +str(tot))
print('Average customer distance (mad2):' +str(mad2))
print('Average customer distance (mad3):' +str(mad3))
print('Percent of customers <= 50 miles (mpi2):' +str(mpi2))
print('Percent of customers <= 50 miles (mpi3):' +str(mpi3))

dc = np.array(['Boston', 'Nashua', 'Providence', 'Springfield', 'Worcester'])
cities = ['Boston', 'Brattleboro', 'Concord', 'Hartford', 'Manchester', 'Nashua',
          'New Haven', 'New London', 'Portsmouth', 'Providence', 'Springfield', 'Worcester']
data = {cities[0]: p1t[0], cities[1]: p1t[1], cities[2]: p1t[2], cities[3]: p1t[3],
       cities[4]: p1t[4], cities[5]: p1t[5], cities[6]: p1t[6], cities[7]: p1t[7],
       cities[8]: p1t[8], cities[9]: p1t[9], cities[10]: p1t[10], cities[11]: p1t[11]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = dc)
df
```

Here is the solution:

```
[[1102.    0.   43.    0.  110.   86.    0.    0.   66.    0.    0.  182.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   28.    0.  495.    0.    0.]
 [   0.   12.    0.  125.    0.    0.  129.    0.    0.    0. 1480.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]
[1. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
The minimum cost is:66285.0
Average customer distance (mad2):20.781786941580755
Average customer distance (mad3):9.405132192846034
Percent of customers <= 50 miles (mpi2):1.9873997709049256
Percent of customers <= 50 miles (mpi3):0.8994297563504406
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and for your suggestions to make it more efficient, I did not know those options for the solver. Regarding 'mpi3', the formula for that constraint states that the right hand side of the equation is equal to the sum of the demands ( https://ibb.co/Lkh5Nkc ), but I think it is a good idea to use 'np.sum(p1)' since the equation that relates those two is the demand constraint, of course we must asume that they are equal. Again, thank you very much.for your answer, it was very helpful.